# node.js, can external request alter variables in a running function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I've set up a node server to save logging information.  It is anticipated to have a very very high volume of requests coming in.  I was working with a mongo data store, but that performance of that too unreliable.  Reading the data on the reporting side of things often took an abnormally long time.  So I switch to a classic, mysql.  There is obviously significant write throughput advantages if you prepare bulk inserts as opposed to do singleton inserts.  So I found this guy:

https://gist.github.com/3078520

I love it's simplicity.  It's on a handful of lines and is very very powerful.  It has two main functions `add()` which will add a record to the queue and then call `flush()` once the queue hits a certain size.  And then it has `flush()` which joins the queue into one long string and creates a long bulk insert statement that is then shipped to the mysql driver (I simplified the function from the supplied link:

```
this.flush = function () {
/*1*/    var sql = queryTemplate.replace('{values}', '\n('+ queue.join('),\n(') +')');
/*2*/    handle.query(sql, callback);
/*3*/    queue = [];
}
```

This is essentially a class function that is part of a single class instance owned by the request handler.  So my question is, is this safe?  The `queue` is a class variable.  When `flush()` is called, it handles the queue.  The only problem I could see would be if `flush()` is called, line 1 is executed to make the sql statement (just a string), **then another `add()` is called that adds something to the `queue`,** then the first process calls the `query()` function and then empties the queue.  In that case, the record that was added by the second process would be lost because the first process wouldn't have known about it when it created the sql statement and would wipe it out when it clears the `queue`.  Is this possible?

A more generalized form of this question would be as follows.  Once a function begins executing, can anything else externally influence variables that have a scope outside of it?  Here's a very simple example, is it ever **possible** to do the console.log in this example presuming different requests call these two functions:

```
var global_number;
function a(){
  global_number=2;
}
function b(){
  global_number=1;
  if(global_number==2){
    console.log("a() influenced global_number in the middle of b()'s execution")
  }
}
```

This is mostly a yes/no question, but I'm looking for a little more than that.  A brief explanation or a link to a page where I can learn more would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the execution of functions are async, then you may have a problem with the data owned by a global variable. Here is the test scenario;

```
var globalVariable = 10;

function a ()
{
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        globalVariable--;
        console.log(globalVariable)
    }, 1000);
}

function b ()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        globalVariable = 20;
    }, 3000);
}

a();
b();
```

This will out put :

```
9
8
7
19
18
17
16
```

If you ask to function execution interruption which is not async, no way! See the example.

```
var globalVariable = 1000000000;
function a () {
    for(var i=0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        if(globalVariable == 20000) console.log('From a() : ' + globalVariable);
        globalVariable--;
        if(globalVariable == 0) break;
    }
}

function b () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('From b() : ' + globalVariable);
        globalVariable = 20000;
        console.log('From b() : ' + globalVariable);
    }, 1);
}

b();
a();
```

This will always output:

```
From a() : 20000
From b() : 0
From b() : 20000
```

So, your questions answer is NO, you can not interrupt a sync function execution.

However; in your code snippet example, it seems to ok to empty the `queue` since you have already consumed the data in the `queue` with `queue.join` at line 1. On the other hand, this approach suffers from rollback operation. When the sql returns an error you may not be able to repopulate the `queue`, for example.

Comment: good point on the error issue, i'm not concerned with it, but it is good to keep in mind.  other than that, is the function safe from data loss in the manner I described? your answer above isn't really clear on that.

Comment: The first sentence is about your actual question. No, it is not safe, your async function can modify the global data, and all the other processes that uses the same global variable are influenced by the manipulated data.

Comment: updated the answer, see the output, you will get the trick easily.

Comment: that is more clear, but my question is can a global variable be altered midway through a single function's execution.  related to your example, there are various calls to a() and b(), each call is async (they have to be, you wait a second), but there's a contention at the 3 second mark when they both execute at the same time.  does one just (randomly) go first, execute to completion and then the other one goes? or, in other words, in this example, once `a()` starts, is it possible for `b()` to run **before that `a()` finishes executing**?

Comment: I see now. Then the answer is no. You cannot interrupt a function execution. See the updated answer.

Comment: great, that is what I wanted, so a() will do that **whole** loop (which will take a tangible amount of time) before b() even starts to execute.  That's what I suspected.  Thanks for the good example!

Answer (score 1):

If a function is synchronous, then nothing can influence the variables referenced by that function between the time the function starts executing and when it completes.

However, if the function calls an asynchronous function (e.g. a MySQL query), then the function itself is asynchronous and other code can modify variables in the parent/global scope of the function between the time the function runs and the time the asynchronous function's callback runs.

Comment: I know the `query()` call is async and will return at a later point in time, but when it's called it knows the sql statement. but is the rest of the function synchronous?  Is it possible to lose a record in the function above in the manner that I described?